# Inheritance Of Generics And fluent APIs

Tags: c#

Hello I am using the builder pattern and am having a Bit of trouble I'm hoping that you can help me out.

First I have a `TableBuilder`and it can build basic Tables like:

```
public abstract class TableBuilder:QueryBuilder
{
    public TableBuilder(Query query)
    {/* do things here*/}

    public TableBuilder Add(string tableName)
    {
        //do things to create a table
        return this;
    }
}
```

And I may want some sub classes from this like:

```
public class SelectTableBuilder:TableBuilder
{
    public SelectTableBuilder ChageStuff(string tableName)
    {
        //do cool stuff here
        return this;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class CrossTabTableBuilder:TableBuilder
{
    public CrossTabTableBuilder DoOtherCoolThings(string name)
    {
        // do work here
        return this;
    }
}
```

So Now I have a `QueryBuilder` that looks something like:

```
public abstract class QueryBuilder
{        

    public Query Query {get;}
    public abstract TableBuilder Tables { get; }
}
```

And a subclasses of this:

```
public class SelectQueryBuilder : QueryBuilder
{
    public override TableBuilder Tables=> new SelectTableBuilder(Query);
}

public class CrossTabQueryBuilder : QueryBuilder
{
    public override TableBuilder Tables => new CrossTabTableBuilder(Query);
}
```

okay, so now when i go to access the `Tables.Add` method I loose the API of the correct table builder. How can I use Generics to make this return the correct API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the `QueryBuilder` generic like this.

```
public abstract class QueryBuilder<T> where T : TableBuilder
{ 
    public Query Query {get;}
    public abstract T Tables { get; }
}
```

Then the implementations would be

```
public class SelectQueryBuilder : QueryBuilder<SelectTableBuilder>
{
    public override SelectTableBuilder Tables=> new SelectTableBuilder(Query);
}

public class CrossTabQueryBuilder : QueryBuilder<CrossTabTableBuilder>
{
    public override CrossTabTableBuilder Tables => new CrossTabTableBuilder(Query);
}
```

I'm not sure how you'd change `TableBuilder` since it also inherits from `QueryBuilder`.  Just from what you're showing I'm not sure it should inherit from `QueryBuilder` at all.

Comment: thank you for your reply but I am getting a compile time error @ `TableBuilder:QueryBuilder<TBuilder>`

Comment: @JamTay317 That's what my comment at the end is about.  Why does `TableBuilder` inherit from `QueryBuilder`?  That creates an odd cycle of a `QueryBuilder` containing a `TableBuilder` which is a `QueryBuilder` which contains a `TableBuilder` and so on.  I recommend makeing `TableBuilder` stand on it's own or move common logic in `QueryBuild` and `TableBuilder` to another class they can both inherit from.

Comment: It inherits from `QueryBuilder` so that you can go somthing like `queryBuilder.Tables.... .Where.... .OrderBy.